# Permissions error with "//proc/tty/driver" in PHPUnit and Jenkins?

Tags: php, testing, jenkins, phpunit, xdebug

I am attempting to run a build on Jenkins running Ubuntu 14.04. My PHPUnit is crashing with the below error message, but there doesn't seem to much out there regarding this error. My xdebug appears to be loading correctly. I am running PHPUnit v4.8.10.

When I try to run `phpunit` via the command line directly, it just hangs and doesn't return. What am I missing?

```
 phpunit: 
 [phpunit] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'UnexpectedValueException' with message 'RecursiveDirectoryIterator::__construct(//proc/tty/driver): failed to open dir: Permission denied' in /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/Some other job/workspace/vendor/phpunit/php-file-iterator/src/Factory.php:66
 [phpunit] Stack trace:
 [phpunit] #0 [internal function]: RecursiveDirectoryIterator->__construct('//proc/tty/driv...', 512)
 [phpunit] #1 [internal function]: RecursiveDirectoryIterator->getChildren()
 [phpunit] #2 [internal function]: FilterIterator->rewind()
 [phpunit] #3 /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/Some other job/workspace/vendor/phpunit/php-file-iterator/src/Factory.php(66): AppendIterator->append(Object(File_Iterator))
 [phpunit] #4 /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/Some other job/workspace/vendor/phpunit/php-file-iterator/src/Facade.php(38): File_Iterator_Factory->getFileIterator(Array, '.php', '', Array)
 [phpunit] #5 /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/Some other job/workspace/vendor/phpunit/php-code-coverage/src/CodeCoverage/Filter.php(112): File_Iterator_Facade->getFilesAsArray('/', '.php', '')
 [phpunit] #6 /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/Some other job/workspace/vend in /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/Some other job/workspace/vendor/phpunit/php-file-iterator/src/Factory.php on line 66

 BUILD FAILED
 /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/Some other job/workspace/build.xml:169: exec returned: 255
```

PHP Info:

```
 PHP 5.5.9-1ubuntu4.13 (cli) (built: Sep 29 2015 15:24:49)
 Copyright (c) 1997-2014 The PHP Group
 Zend Engine v2.5.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2014 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.0.3, Copyright (c) 1999-2014, by Zend Technologies
    with Xdebug v2.2.3, Copyright (c) 2002-2013, by Derick Rethans
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with my whitelisting inside my `phpunit.xml`. As you can see in the `<directory>` tag, I was telling my code coverage to start at the root of the server! Which is how it ended up looking through my sockets and getting caught somewhere it shouldn't have been.

**To resolve this**, change the `<directory suffix=".php">/</directory>` below to `<directory suffix=".php">./</directory>` so the code coverage only looks through your project directory.

The old filter:

```
<filter>
    <whitelist addUncoveredFilesFromWhitelist="true">
        <directory suffix=".php">/</directory>
        <exclude>
            <file>bootstrap/autoload.php</file>
        </exclude>
    </whitelist>
</filter>
```